# Philosophers who have written on aesthetics of ideas

Tags: sociology

One example I can give is the book "Fashion, Faith and Fantasy" by Roger Penrose. There he talks about the Fashion, Faith and Fantasy of popular physics theories, for instance ones like string theory, M theory and the likes.

Similar to this, but on a more abstract level, are there any philosophers who have written on the aesthetics of Ideas? As in, why certain ideas would be more palpatable/ fashionable to most members in society than others.